# "Proper" way to define a class - Properties vs Methods

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is an observation and a question:

I am loading some json data into a class (json already converted into an NSDictionary). The values will be read-only from the outside:

```
@interface Checklist
-(id)initWithJSON:(NSDictionary *)json;
-(NSInteger)checklist_id;
-(NSString *)checklist_name;
etc....
@end
```

With the corresponding method bodies in the .m file.

As a test, I created a class for another data element:

```
@interface ChecklistItem
-(id)initWithJSON:(NSDictionary *)json;
@property (readonly) NSInteger item_id;
@property (readonly) NSString *item_name;
@end
```

Functionally, the two classes have similar methods in the @implementation. In both cases they basically pull the appropriate value from the json and return the result. And as far as the rest of the program was concerned, the two approaches seem to be interchangeable.

So my question is:

Which approach is the best one to use?

I find either way equally readable and so far I can not find any code-reason to prefer one way over the other. I can kind of see the second option as nice since it kind-of documents the json.

Comment: One point in favor of the second \@property way of defining the class:

Inside the \@implementation, I do not have to define private objects to cache results. I can just \@synthesize and use the _property values.

Comment: if your using LLVM you don't need to even use synthesize.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use properties, they come in handy once you use [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html).

Also you can define public readonly properties and overwrite them in a class extension with a readwrite property that is only usable in the same class. If you try to achieve something similar you will have to deal with private helper methods — the code gets ugly.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> -(NSInteger)checklist_id;
> -(NSString *)checklist_name;
> ```

This isn't standard Objective-C naming.  If you want to do things properly, follow the platform conventions.  Apple document this in their coding guidelines documentation.

> Which approach is the best one to use?

They are equivalent as far as Objective-C is concerned.  The property syntax expresses your intent at a higher level than manually creating the methods, so I would prefer that approach.  It's also less code.

Comment: I am going back through my code to fix the method/property names... most of them came over directly from the underlying json, thus the use of underscores...

Answer (score 0):

This is less important now that ARC will clean up memory which would have been managed
inside the setter but this is still very much best practice. The performance overhead of
calling a setter method is also negligible compared to the safety gained from always
going through the setter.

Answer (score 0):

this is a subjective question and you'll get nothing but opinions back, but here is mine:

the read only properties will just write the getters for you.  if you don't write a private read write propertly in your .m file or wherever and just set the ivar's directly you don't even get the will/did change value for key calls and will have to call those yourself also.

```
@interface ChecklistItem ()
    @property (readwrite) NSInteger item_id;
    @property (readwrite) NSString *item_name;
@end
```

To access them KVO complient inside the object you'll have to do:

```
self.item_id = 13;
```

And not:

```
_item_id = 13;
```

Of course you could just have getter methods:

```
-(NSInteger)checklist_id;
-(NSString *)checklist_name;
```

And just wrap all changes in in your KVO methods:

```
[self willChangeValueForKey:@"checklist_id"];
_item_id = 13;
[self didChangeValueForKey:@"checklist_id"];
```

it's just a coding style choice, and sometimes leveraging what the compiler will write for you. but either option works the same.

Answer (score -1):

If the values are read only, I'd think you'd want them as methods rather than as read-only properties to avoid any confusion that the values might be able to be set.  Unless of course you want the subscribers to be able to use the dot notation for accessing the properties, but if you're just returning the values in the NSDictionary, the method form would be better as you're not keeping around another copy of the data.

Comment: Why not simply using properties and overriding the getters which would in fact pull the data from that dictionary? => et viola, no double data and still very convenient usage.